# hook_form_alter selecting a default value in a node reference select list

Tags: nodes, entities, 6

I am trying to add some logic to auto select a node reference option on a select list on my content type. I am trying to set it with the following.

```
$form['field_my_field']['#default_value'][0]['nid'] = 5;
```

Where 5 is a nid. The value is set correctly in the form but when it is rendered to the page the option in the select list is not selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like a good approach to me. Can you provide more context, eg. which hook you're using, maybe provide the whole hook; also can you say what if anything is selected instead?

Answer (score 2):

CCK requires a little voodoo to alter values with a [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6). You need to implement a special type: `after_build`, so put this code in a `custom.module`:

```
//Declare the callback for after_build for page node form
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'page_node_form) {
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'custom_after_build';
  }
}

function custom_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  //Set my node ref to 5
  $form['field_node']['nid']['nid']['#value'][0] = 5;
  //you can set more than one using 
  $form['field_node']['nid']['nid']['#value'][2] = 6;
  //have a look at the form after after_build
  dsm($form);
  return $form;
}
```

I adapted a [previous answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8747/how-to-default-value-to-select-list-cck-with-form-alter/8766#8766) of mine, but I have to admin that node reference is even more confusing ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to docs you should:

```
'#default_value' => variable_get('field_my_field','5');
```

btw, maybe use javascript is the easiest way?

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs page you are looking at.

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#select

Comment: @drupality CCK elements don't always follow normal FAPI practices.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a direct value to it. e.g.

```
$form['field_my_field']['#default_value'] = 5;
```

Comment: The option does not seem to be selected....

Comment: @Shoaib I don't think this is ever right.