# Replace default words in exposed filters

Tags: views, 6

I created an exposed view that allows users to sort content based on content type or date. In my content type drop down menu, the default choice is - Any -, I tried to replace it in the settings file's string override section, but while this works for numerous other defaults, it doesn't seem to be taking for exposed views. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to resolve from backend/server side, but without success, so I have reviewed a way using Jquery (client side), while an backend alternative is achieved:

```
<script>
$("#here-field-name option[value='All']").html("Anytext");  
</script>
```

Also, here is alternatives from backend perspective, maybe are useful for you [how to default value to select list CCK with form_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8747/how-to-default-value-to-select-list-cck-with-form-alter)

I hope information be useful.

Answer (score 0):

go to the folder : sites\all\modules\views\handlers and open the
views_handler_filter.inc file...

and search for :"- Any-" in the file...
one of them is located in the  "exposed_translate" function.
change it to whatever you what.
it is a little bit hacky but it works ;)